# add layer on top of an existing div

Tags: css, dropzone.js

I have a div whose contents are filled dynamically. Basically it displays a list

```
<div id="searchResult"></div>
```

i also have a separate div for dropping of files. I am using Dropzone for uploading of files

```
<div class="filesDropzone dz-clickable" id="filesDrop" style="width:97%;height:50px;"></div>
```

But now i need to include this dropzone div into searchResult div. Basically, when user drags a file the dropzone area needs to be displayed on top of searchresult.

Is there any quick way to achieve this type of layering output?

Comment: Have you tried z-index?

Comment: yes, i have tried previously as:<div>
<div class="filesDropzone dz-clickable" id="filesDrop" style="width:97%;height:50px;z-index:2"></div>
<div id="searchResult" style="z-index:1"></div>
</div> It did not work. However if i use z index then it wont cover the searchresult div entirely. isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Put both div in position: absolute and their parent in position: relative, then use z-index to avoid problems.

Example :

Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS (actually SCSS for nesting but it's the same)

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;

    & .content,
    & .overlay{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    & .content{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: orange;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    & .overlay{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/ZYgEBj